# JavaFX: Trying to run the command line 'pdflatex myfile.tex'

Tags: compilation, javafx, latex, command-line-arguments

My question is two parts.

### First part:

I am writing a series of latex files, and I would like to compile them.

The command works if I type it manually. so the syntax should be correct. But when I run it from java application, it won't compile.

This code, in Java creates a latex file correctly--as expected.

```
File latexFile = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(window.stage);
if (latexFile != null) {
    try {
        writeContentToFile(content, latexFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DocumentViewPort.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I can compile the generated file in the command line if I type `pdflatex` and then add the file path and get a `PDF file`.

but it does not seem to work when doing it from java itself like in here:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "pdflatex " + latexFile.getPath());
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FileAndContentCreation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

any ideas why?
I tried to read online on many places, I can't find out what part is the problematic one. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

### Second part

My second part of the question is changing the directory, I am using:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cd " + myNewdirectory.getPath());
```

But it fails with an `error=2`

Any ideas how to change the current directory?

Comment: Does the command `pdflatex` need any other input ? Why do you need to change the directory ?

Comment: Hi, no it does not need other output. The same command works on the same file if I run it manually from the command line. for the directory, If i don't change it, the pdf gets created in the user folder, but I want it to do in a specific folder. when I do cd mydir then pdflatex myfile.tex from the command line, it all works. but from java's runtime, neither one works.

Comment: Check what `"pdflatex "+latexFile.getPath()` is evaluating to

Comment: Also, instead of changing directory, try (something like) `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pdflatex -output-directory "+myNewDirectory.getPath()+" "+latexFile.getPath());` Check the documentation for `pdflatex`, but iirc that is the correct option.

Comment: Thanks the change directory worked! and the compile to PDF worked.! The only thing I found strange is that compiling command won't work if the folder name had white space in it... any ideas why?

Comment: /can you add your answer as an "Answer" so that the question gets closed :) ?

Comment: For the first part, you have to capture the std out and std error, or else it won't work. See [a similar post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33298548/pdflatex-run-crashes-when-executed-from-java-on-windows)